# Showing the data coming to the IP printer on the Screen-ESC Parse

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

Project: Flutter/Dart or with Java - Python Decompiler

I want to show the data coming to an IP Printer in the kitchen on the screen. I have developed an App with an IP Thermal printer that works with Flutter. But I would like to develop a driver to show this to the kitchen staff on a Screen. If anyone has an idea, can you write about how I can do this?
Or how does the data come to the IP printer? Does anyone know how this came about?
I found an app on Google Play, where I can create a virtual IP Thermal text, specify the IP address, and send data directly to it, and then I can see the screen of my phone. But I want to show this incoming data on a screen. Or I want to collect the incoming data in a list at the back and show it directly.

```
Printer Link - https://www.epson.eu/en_EU/products/retail/pos-printers/pos-printer-%28tm%29/epson-tm-t20iii-series/p/28271

App Google Play - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.a402d.rawbtprinter&hl=de&gl=US

Pub.dev Plugins for Flutter/Dart
https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils, 
https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer, 
https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer,
```

That can be also helpfully,
https://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinter_pos-virtual-printer.html

Thanks for all your Responses.

Comment: It will be difficult because we are trying to handle data that has already been encoded for the printer. How about creating an image or HTML text to be displayed on the screen from the data that was the basis for creating print data?

Comment: Its working, but i got Third Softwares and they are sending data to Thermal Printer , i would show the Datas from third Software Incoming Datas .

Comment: It's not a direct answer, but this article may be helpful. [Safely ignoring unknown ANSI, ESC/P, ESC/POS sequences, know the length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71143625/9014308)